# Understanding AWS Sagemaker limits and thier requests

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I want to know that is their any console where I can easily see, that what is my current limit of different resources,eg like ml.p2.2xlarge.
Also , I am not getting that , if I am training my model in sagemaker on instance:'ml.c4.xlarge', now if I got limit error, now I should request increase of what: EC2 instance, notebook instance.....
Please guide me thoroughly through this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to see all SageMaker service quota limits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71655510/how-to-see-all-sagemaker-service-quota-limits)

Answer (score 0):

So for your training jobs, you can go into the console, select your resource, scroll down and you will find a monitor section where you can see your CPU, memory and disk util.

[image]

For the notebooks, you can have a look into the cloudwatch logs, but while training the notebook is not used but the EC2 instance.

Comment: Thanks for your concern, but which console I have to refer to for selecting my resource.

Comment: The AWS Console, the UI.

Answer (score 0):

SageMaker account-level limits are not visible in the console. In order to request a limit increase, you need to open a support ticket. For example in your case, if you cannot launch a training of the desired instance type, you need to open the support ticket for the specific SageMaker Training instance type. SageMaker limits are not related to your EC2 limits.