# How to see all SageMaker service quota limits?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I believe there are different limits for SageMaker training, vs CreateTransformJob, spot vs not dedicated. Where can I see the current service limits for sagemaker services? Is there a place to check all SageMaker service quotas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sagemaker.html) in the documentation you can see the default sagemaker service quotas. Unfortunately, it's not yet possible to see the current quotas according to this [post](https://repost.aws/questions/QUweO83CSlTu-3Zn2RxdESWg/how-do-i-check-my-current-sage-maker-service-quotas).

Answer (score 2):

SageMaker is now integrated with Service Quotas for viewing and adjusting limits. See [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/regions-quotas.html#regions-quotas-quotas).